# How can I match just the first line of occurrence?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
$str = "11ff11
        22mm22
        33gg33
        mm22mm
        vv55vv
        77ll77
        55kk55
        kk22kk
        bb11bb";
```

There is two kind of patterns:

1. `{two numbers}{two letters}{two numbers}`
2. `{two letters}{two numbers}{two letters}`

I'm trying to match the first line when pattern changes. So I want to match these:

```
11ff11  -- this
22mm22
33gg33
mm22mm  -- this
vv55vv
77ll77  -- this
55kk55
kk22kk  -- this
bb11bb
```

Here is my [current pattern](https://regex101.com/r/aI6zS1/1):

```
/(\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2})|([a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2})/
```

But it matches all lines ..! How can I limit it to match just first line of same pattern?

Comment: you'd need lookarounds. as written, you ARE matching every line, because you're specified a per-line match that allows both types of lines.

Comment: Another lookaround based idea: [`\b(?:\A|(?<=\d\n)(?!\d)|(?<=\D\n)(?=\d)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/sF8mV8/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not do it with lookaround due to the problem with spaces. But with classic regex it's available. It finds sequences of repeating pattern and capture only he first one

```
(?:(\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2})\s+)(?:\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2}\s+)*|(?:([a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2})\s+)(?:[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\s+)*
```

[demo and some explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/zN5eU6/2)

To understand how it works i made simple exmple with patterns of digit and  letter:

```
(?:(\d)\s+)(?:\d\s+)*|(?:(a)\s+)(?:a\s+)*
```

[demo and some explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/mF9hF1/3)

Comment: @stack have you seen demo?

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Comment: @splash58 It is better to replace the "\s+" with "\s*" because one of the matches can be the last line on the list (does not have a new line at the end).

Comment: @splash58 your solution works like a charm. It is the best answer. Only remove the non-capturing groups of the beginning. The result will be the same without them: `(\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2})\s*(?:\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2}\s*)*|([a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2})\s*(?:[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\s*)*`

Comment: @elchininet Yes, you are right. I did it for uniformity. Don't think it make it less effective :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do this with only one expression, but you can iterate over your string and test when changes:

```
<?php

$str = "11ff11
        22mm22
        33gg33
        mm22mm
        vv55vv
        77ll77
        55kk55
        kk22kk
        bb11bb";

$exploded = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$patternA = '/(\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2})/';
$patternB = '/([a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2})/';

$result = [];
$currentPattern = '';

//get first and check what pattern is
if(preg_match($patternA, $exploded[0])){
    $currentPattern = $patternA;
    $result[] = $exploded[0];
} elseif(preg_match($patternB, $exploded[0])){
    $currentPattern = $patternB;
    $result[] = $exploded[0];
} else {
    //.. no pattern on first element, should we continue?
}

//toggle
$currentPattern = $currentPattern == $patternA ? $patternB : $patternA;

foreach($exploded as $e) {
    if(preg_match($currentPattern, $e)) {
        //toggle
        $currentPattern = $currentPattern == $patternA ? $patternB : $patternA;
        $result[] = trim($e);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "11ff11"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "mm22mm"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "77ll77"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "kk22kk"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take. Never used lookbehinds before and well, my regex skills are not that good but this does seem to return what you want.

```
/^.*|(?<=[a-z]{2}\n)\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{2}|(?<=\d{2}\n)[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}/
```

Comment: Good solution @georaldc. Only add the capturing groups to the matches. Regards ;)